# Scratched images in Chrome

Tags: css, image

Maybe for many this puzzle is simple, but not for me. Firefox and Chrome render images differently (technical drawing).  I tried using `image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;` or `image-rendering: pixelated;` but it doesn't solve the problem. Still the images are jagged.
I'm ussing photoshop and illustrator for saving images.
Thank you in advance for your help.

**Firefox**

[image]

**Chrome**

[image]

**My css**

**File**

```css
.img-responsive-select {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast;
}
```

```html
<tr>
  <td width="30%"><label>Technical drawing:</label></td>
  <td width="70%"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/360x120" class="img-responsive img-responsive-select" /></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

Photoshop->high pass->value '1'(overlay) and add 0,2 blur

**html chrome output**

[image]